# What are the default sounds for iOS 7?

Tags: notifications, ios

I upgraded both my iOS devices to iOS 7, so I have my custom sound preferences that I took with me. However I would like to try the default sounds, preferably without restoring my my devices to factory defaults.

Can someone please tell me which sound goes with which alert type (new mail, etc.)?

Comment: They are listed beside each sound. So for AirDrop, it will say Pulse (Default). They will each have that "(Default)" suffix attached to them. That is the default sound attached to that action.

Comment: @cksum Can you post this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @patrix done...

Comment: So the default sounds that existed previously have not changed? Because the ones I checked were listed in "Classic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are listed beside each sound.

If we look at AirDrop for example, iOS will list: Pulse (Default).

All sounds will have this **(Default)** suffix attached to them.

[image]

Comment: lets make this one a 10k!